# Downloading compressed content over HTTP using Python

Tags: python, http, compression, gzip, httplib2

How do I take advantage of HTTP 1.1's compression when downloading web pages using Python?

I am currently using the built-in [**urllib**](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) module for downloading web content.  Reading through the documentation I couldn't find any information that is indeed using compression.

Is it already built-in into **urllib** or is there another library that I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) supports 'deflate' and 'gzip' compression.

**Example**

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
resp, content = h.request("http://example.org/", "GET")
```

The content is decompressed as necessary.