# Python2 download binary file using server site compression

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, compression

Searching through Stackoverflow I found a lot of answers how to download a file with Python (may it be using urllib2, requests etc), but only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316517/downloading-compressed-content-over-http-using-python) for using compression (httplib2). Sadly this answer is not using streams.

How can I download a large binary file with Python using compression and streams?

What I currently use is to slow and looks the following:

```
def get_large_file_a(url, file, length): # using requests

    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        for data in tqdm(
                response.iter_content(),
                total=length,
                unit='B',
                unit_scale=True,
        ):
            f.write(data)
```